# Why can't we use 什么的 ("and so on") with lists of people, and what can we use instead?

Tags: usage

My Chinese text book says this about using [什么的](http://dict.cn/%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E7%9A%84) ("and so on"):

[image: photo from Chinese text book]

I transcribe and translate this below (ignoring the first line; it's an example of using 什么的 continuing from the previous page):

> [注意](http://dict.cn/%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F)：”什么的“[只能](http://dict.cn/%E5%8F%AA%E8%83%BD)用于[物](http://dict.cn/%E7%89%A9)，不能用于人。[例如](http://dict.cn/%E4%BE%8B%E5%A6%82)，不能说：“我们[班](http://dict.cn/%E7%8F%AD)有[韩国人](http://dict.cn/%E9%9F%A9%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA)，[美国人](http://dict.cn/%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA)，[日本人](http://dict.cn/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA)什么的。” 
>   Attention: "什么的" can only be used with things, not with people.  For example, we cannot say "our class has Korean people, American people, Japanese people, and so on."
>   <sub>Zhùyì: ”Shénme de“ zhǐnéng yòng yú wù, bùnéng yòng yú rén. Lìrú, bùnéng shuō: “Wǒmen bān yǒu Hánguórén, Měiguórén, Rìběnrén shénme de.”</sub>

**Question**: Why can't we use 什么的 with lists of people, and what can we use instead?

The book doesn't discuss why we can't say this, only that we can't.  I guess it's because it's impolite to say this, but I'm just guessing.

I also don't know what we can use as an alternative (e.g. 等等 instead of 什么的), since whatever reason we should not use 什么的 might also apply to the alternative.

Comment: It's because 什么的 refers to 'things'. It's not good to mess up people with things.

Comment: reminder of use of 什么 w/o 的 while referring to people：cf. ＂实用现代汉语语法＂＂什么＂作定语时，也可以修饰指人的名词，如   **＂什么人＂、＂什么大夫＂、＂什么工程师＂**  ，代姓名、职业等。
＂什么人＂和＂谁＂表达的意思基本一样，都是问人的姓名、职业、身份，如＂他是谁？＂＂他是什么人？＂但＂什么人＂不够客气礼貌。＂他是你什么人？＂是问＂他＂与＂你＂的关系，这时不能说＂他是你的谁？＂。

Comment: example of 什么的 "and what not,and others" after 男友 in  电视剧惊情48小时：第6集  http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XODA3Nzg2NDg4.html?spm=a2h0j.8191423.vpofficiallistv5_wrap.5~5~5~5!6~A 

see 05:25:我听说她有那个绯闻男友什么的  spoken by high ranking detective
０４：２３：我就是想听听你对她的看法
０４：２８：从她七年前到宏美来的那一天起
０４：３１：我就看出来了 她会成功
０４：３４：她会走到事业的顶端
０４：３６：怎么肯定
０４：３９：想吃这碗饭的人我见多了
０４：４１：不瞒你说
０４：４３：大多是为了名利
０４：４５：理解
０４：４６：古来如此
０４：４７：可白冰冰不一样
０４：４８：她好像还有别人不具备的东西
０４：５３：这是我们需要的
０４：５５：她可以为了达到一个目的
０４：５７：不惜去付出一切
０４：５９：你能不能具体点儿
０５：０３：就像去年贺岁档的
０５：０４：和那个香港合拍片０５：０７：里面有几句广东话的台词
０５：０９：她请家教就学了两个月
０５：１３：有激情是好的
０５：１５：但激情需要控制

Comment: ０５：１９：白冰冰有男朋友吗 ０５：２３：还没有 ０５：２４：不对呀 ０５：２５：我听说 **她有那个绯闻男友什么的**  ０５：２８：就是那个潘晓东 ０５：３１：都是媒体乱写 为了吸引眼球

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be used for people because 什么的 means "things like"

> 写写信、打打球、洗洗衣服**什么的** =  "**Things like** writing letter, playing basketball, washing clothes"

Also;

> To list specific individuals, we can use '等人'
>
> Example:  陈博士，李教授，王法官**等人** (Dr. Chen, Professor Li, Judge Wang and **others like them**)

~

> To list different kinds of people or things, we can use '之類'
>
> Example:
>
> '医生，律师 和警察**之類** ' (**people like** doctor, lawyer and police)
>
> '足球，篮球 和网球**之類**' (**things like** football, basketball and tennis)

~

> 'and so on' = "等等"
>
> Example:
>
> '足球，篮球, 网球**等等**' (football, basketball, tennis **and so on**)
>
> '医生，律师, 警察**等等**' (doctor, lawyer, police **and so on**)

~

> To list different kinds of dishonorable people, we can use '之流'

Example: "小偷, 騙子和走私客**之流**" (**the like of** thief, con man and  smuggler)

Comment: TIP: 等等 could be replaced with single character 等.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it's because it's impolite to say this, but I'm just guessing.

What you guessed is right. More precisely, when `什么的` is used for listing it has negative connotations. Such as the sentence you showed,

> 课余时间写写信、打打球、洗洗衣服什么的。
>
> During spare time (I only) write letters, play balls, wash clothes, etc.
>
> **[connotation]** I don't have much time to do those interesting things.

That means, according to the context, if it matches your intent you can also use it with people.

As an alternative `等等` is fine, basically it's a neutral word, doesn't have any negative or positive connotations.